# Selenium Drop Down Menu - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, dropdownbox

I'm using the xpath and index method to select a value from a drop down menu. Here's an example of what I have:

```
## Go to the website
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://something.com/something/app/reports")
## Select a report type
obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportType"]'))
obj.select_by_index(9)
```

My report type DOES change to index 9 after I run this code, but it does not prompt the website to load more of the page like it normally would have if I manually selected index 9.

So the code fills the text box, but it does not prompt the page to continue as it should. Do I need to add some type of click or submit method?

Comment: Silly question: have you _tried_ a `click` or `submit` method?

Comment: You should do exactly the same as you're doing manually: if selecting the option is enough, then no, you don't need a `click` or `submit`... If `select` is inside a `form` and you need to press "Enter" to confirm your choice, then yeah, try `submit()`, why not...

Comment: @Jelena Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @G.Anderson I have, but I may be formatting it incorrect since I get this error message "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'"

Comment: @Andersson I've tried using sendKeys(Keys.ENTER), but I also get an attribute error and am not sure how to properly format it

Comment: Also, thank you all for the responses! I appreciate the feedback

Comment: If you're getting a `NoneType` related error, it means that whatever you're trying to click doesn't exist, or isn't being selected the way you think it is. Are you able to verify that your elements are being correctly selected prior to the attempted submit action?

Comment: The code I have changes the text box from "Select a Report Type" to "Power Usage Report" which is what I want it do, but it does not actually click/ expend the page after it has been selected. It faintly shoes the text "Power Usage Report", while manually selecting the report type writes the text in a bold font. Could it be that I'm formatting the code incorrectly? Right now I have "obj.select_by_index(9).sendKeys(Keys.Enter)" @G.Anderson

Comment: It sounds like you may have nested/ajax menus, which don't play well with selenium in my experience. Without the actual page to test against, here's my usual flow: On the page in a manual browser window, can you navigate to the same menu/target using arrow and tab keys on your keyboard? That can help indicate what your automation has to/can do. Sometimes in these menus you have to hit enter, or wait, or hit an arrow key.

Comment: Using my keyboard alone, I can press the tab key to open the drop down menu, then use the down arrow key to navigate the report type I want, and then select it by pressing the enter key. This manual method works perfectly, but I'm not 100% sure if I can code that using selenium. @G.Anderson

Comment: So then, you can 'drive' the selenium driver from something like a jupyter notebook, and try to recreate the exact key presses one at a time and see where it breaks down. Rather than selecting by element, etc, you can just `sendKeys`. It's less robust, but it's worked for me in the past

Comment: Thank you @G.Anderson :) I'll give it a go.

Comment: Hi @G.Anderso I am still having trouble using send keys on BI Oracle can you give me an example of code that you would use in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, because each site handles these things differently, each solution works or doesn't work. *However*, since you're using oracle BI, yiou may be able to simplify the interface using their [accessibility features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/bi.1111/e10544/appeaccess.htm). They have a separate interface for screen readers, which may be easier to render. Additionally, it may be worth looking into getting what you want via API rather than automation, I know theirs is pretty robust if you have access to it.